# It Is possible to send a RST flag in a TIdTCPClient?

Tags: sockets, delphi, vcl, indy10, delphi-xe8

I need to send a `RST` flag in one socket, is it possible?

When I close the `TIdTCPClient`, the TCP server program tells me that the connection is still alive, and after 2 minutes the connection disappears.

I'm doing this :

```
TCPCliente := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
TCPCliente.Host := edtIP.Text;
TCPCliente.Port := 492;
TCPCliente.ConnectTimeout := 1000;
TCPCliente.Connect;
TCPCliente.Socket.WriteLnRFC(TextoEnvio, IndyTextEncoding_8Bit);
Texto := TCPCliente.Socket.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_8Bit);
TCPCliente.Socket.Close;
TCPCliente.Disconnect;
TCPCliente.Free;
```

I'm using RAD Studio XE8.

Comment: Do not call `TCPCliente.Socket.Close()` directly, `TCPCliente.Disconnect()` handles that internally for you.

Comment: Indy performs a graceful disconnect when closing a socket. Use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to verify. If your server thinks the connection is still alive, then either the server has a logic bug, or the client's `FIN` packet is getting lost on the network before the server sees it, such as If you are connecting through a firewall/router/proxy that is dropping its server-side connection incorrectly when your client-side connection disconnects.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I have verified with wiresaherk , and yes, I need to send RST Flag . If I close the application , I see the RST flag is sent , and then the connection ends , but I need to end the connection without closing the application.

Comment: Do you know what `RST` actually is? It is an flag sent by the *operating system* in reply to a packet it received for a non-existent connection (amongst other reasons). It tells the sender to tear down their side of whatever connection they think is open (causing `send()` and similar functions to report an `ECONNRESET` error). It is not something you can send in your code manually, nor should you be trying to. If you are seeing `RST` being sent when your app is closed, then your app has active sockets that it did not close beforehand...

Comment: ... If you want to close a socket connection without closing the app, you need to make sure you close the socket *correctly* so the other party knows it is being closed.  And like I said, Indy already does that by default, so use it the way it is meant to be used (which includes NOT closing the `IOHandler` manually). If you are still having problems with it, I would suspect an issue with your network setup before I suspect a problem with how Indy closes its sockets.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank for answering, but as I see in the wiresark until the RST not sent the connection is active . I tried everything and I think with the code above , the connection should be closed . I think it's kind of timeout , because it is rare that when I close the application,  It sends , or after two minutes, after closing .I've tried everything , and nothing. I've never had this problem , and no longer know what to do.

Comment: `RST` is an *abnormal* disconnect.  A *graceful* disconnect involves both parties sending `FIN` to each other instead. It sounds like your `FIN`s are getting lost, so the parties do not know the connection is closed, and so resort to `RST`. At a later time.  That is a networking issue, not a coding issue. Check if your firewall/router is blocking packets for the connection.